# sorting a collection with a 'double' column

Tags: laravel, database, sorting, collections

I tried to sort a collection, that has a column named 'filesize'.
It is a decimal column, and I've set that in the migration since I want a comma separator in the database, for the column 'filesize'.

But somehow laravel doesn't want to sort the database collection on 'filesize', from the items that I loaded from the db.

The sorting function works however, when I sort on another column. The column 'width' is set to string, and it sorts that column without any problems.

This is the code I used for this example:

```
$duplis->sortby('filesize', 1);
```

I also tried this example, because it is a nested collection that I want to sort:

```
$sorted = $duplis->sortBy(function ($item) {
    //dd($item);
    return $item->filesize;
 }, 3);
```

I hope someone could help.

Thanks!

Comment: duplis is a model? also are sorting relationships as well or just want to sort the model?

Comment: Hi KGG,

duplis is an extracted part of another collection, and that collection comes from the db eventuelly. 

So I try to sort the duplis collection (the extracted part of another collection).

I hope it is more clear now :-)

Comment: can you dd the collection?

Comment: Hi @omaresmaeel,

Here is a screenshot of the collection: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LAdy93tsCKn0GGRqmJ9JgOSKT8o7M0dC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DaveHulst so `filesize` is a string-type column, containing decimal numbers with `,` used as separators instead of `.`. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Christian,

Yes it seems like a ```.``` in the database.

Comment: That ```.``` in the database is the seperator itself. The filesize of each file is shown with megabytes as unit.

Comment: @DaveHulst In your screenshot, I see 2 collections: a top-level collection that contains a nested collection, and the nested collection that holds a list of `Order`s. Is `$duplis` the top-level collection or the nested collection?

Comment: Hi @Christian,

The top level collection is the dupli.
I grouped it using a Eloquent query, on the dupli. 
the ```Order``` is a derivative of that dupli group.

Comment: @DaveHulst Got it. Answer posted, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LAdy93tsCKn0GGRqmJ9JgOSKT8o7M0dC/view), we know that `$duplis` is a collection of key-value pairs, whose:

- keys are numeric (i.e., `4665` in your screenshot), and
- values are sub-collections that contain the `Order`s that need to be sorted.

Given this information, if you want to have a collection of sorted `Order`s, extracted from `$duplis`, then do:

```php
$sorted = $duplis->map(function ($orders) {
    return $orders->sortBy('filesize');
});
```

Comment: Hi Christian,

Thank you, it works like a charm :)